# how do I split a vector of dates into days?

Tags: matlab, date

I have a dataset with dates on 1 column and values on another column

```
'4/26/2016'  23
'4/26/2016'  25
'4/26/2016'  1
'4/27/2016'  10
'4/27/2016'  40
'4/27/2016'  67
'4/28/2016'  24
'4/28/2016'  13
'4/28/2016'  7
'4/28/2016'  99
```

How do I separate the values into different days? e.g., 4/27/2016 will have values of 10, 40 and 67 and so on. The dates might be different depending on the dataset that I am using so there is no fixed dates. Thanks!

Comment: (1) What data-structure and data-types are you using? Post your data as actual MATLAB code (2) what output do you want? Do you want to split this for every date in one go or to want to do it one date at a time? i.e. are you wanting a cell array output or will you be doing this in a loop?

Comment: I want to split the values into different number of vectors in one go based on the number of days. So if there are 5 days in the dates column, i will have 5 vectors of values with each vector referring to values from each day.

Comment: No you definitely do not want to do that, you want to split it into one cell array with 5 elements. Fine, that's easy to do using `accumarray` (or [`splitapply`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) in the latest version) but again, you need to post an actual MATLAB data structure, not just some data you typed out.

Comment: As @Dan said, we need to know your data-structure ! Then I think that you will be interested by the first and the third output of the function `unique`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know what data structure you are using so we'll just have to assume it:

```
%% Your data
dates = {'4/26/2016';'4/26/2016';'4/26/2016';'4/27/2016';...
    '4/27/2016';'4/27/2016';'4/28/2016';'4/28/2016';...
    '4/28/2016';'4/28/2016'};

values = [23; 25; 1; 10; 40; 67; 24; 13; 7; 99];

[uniqueDates,~,sub] = unique(dates)
valuesPerDate = accumarray(sub, values, [], @(x){x})

%OPTIONAL
combined = [uniqueDates, valuesPerDate]
```

I would actually recommend first converting your dates into  the new [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) type, i.e. `dates = datetime(dates)` and then later `combined = [num2cell(uniqueDates), valuesPerDate]`, but if not then at least use a more logical format such as `'yyyy-mm-dd'` so that their alphabetical ordering is the same as their chronological ordering.

Answer (score 2):

```
%% Your data
date = {'4/26/2016';'4/26/2016';'4/26/2016';'4/27/2016';...
    '4/27/2016';'4/27/2016';'4/28/2016';'4/28/2016';...
    '4/28/2016';'4/28/2016'};

data = [23; 25; 1; 10; 40; 67; 24; 13; 7; 99];

%% First convert the date to datenum for ease
date = datenum(date,'mm/dd/yyyy');

%% Get the number of days 
unique_days = unique(date);

%% Loop through the different days and extract corresponding data
%% - You might want to add unique identifiers to the variable names
for idx = 1:length(unique_days)
curr_day = unique_days(idx);  % Get current date
idx_days = date == curr_day;  % indices of data for current date
data_results{idx} = data(idx_days);   % results
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but one shoudl avoid always to use `eval` , its very bad programming practice. Instead, create an array of structs or a cell array

Comment: Thanks! I agree and stated that in my comment before the eval.

Comment: Unfortunately people copy-paste without reading, I encourage you to change the answer to something better!

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri, Just for me to know, what is wrong with `eval` ? Too slow ?

Comment: @obchardon you can read a lot in different places, a quick glance of why is because [even mathworks tells you to avoid it](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/). Come to the MATLAB chatroom to ask about it more.

Comment: @obchardon http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/ but also, it makes your code difficult to read, very difficult to debug, in this case it litters your workspace with many dynamically created variables (which should be in a single container) forcing you to use `eval` to interact with these now for the rest of your script